# Usage of "the same"

Tags: pronouns

> He lent me some money on the condition that I should return the same before November.

Before anyone marks it as possible duplicate of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/30000/212388) question, I would like to add that [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/30000/212388) doesn't answers my question, that question talks about if it is colloquially acceptable to use *the same*, but I am not talking about colloquial usage, I am asking from strictly grammatical point of view. Moreover people over there have just given their 'opinions' but here I am sharing a excerpt from a renowned Author's dictionary.

My book (not written by native speaker but written after consulting 50+ native speakers work) says I need to replace *the same* with *it* because *the same* is always used as a adjective followed by a noun. He has cited the given below excerpt from H.W. Fowler's book.

[image]

Comment: You really only muddy the waters when you say, "I am not talking about colloquial usage, I am asking from strictly grammatical point of view."

Comment: Just because the author uses 50 citations that doesn't mean the book is always correct. 'The same' as a pro-form can substitute for a noun phrase and adjective.

Comment: @user178049 #1  No one said the author uses 50 citations, It's just mentioned in question that  he referred to 50+ different books. #2 No one said the author is correct.

Comment: @user212388 Okay, and you should buy a new book.

Comment: I tend to agree with Fowler on this ("the same" usually comes across to me as jargon or worse), but it's not a grammatical point.  It's a question of usage or style and ultimately subjective.

Answer (score 2):

"[**The same**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/same)" in Dictionary.com has two two suitable definitions as an adjective *(if we consider it to be followed by a noun, which could have been omitted here: **the same amount**)*:

1. *identical with what is about to be or has just been mentioned*
2. *agreeing in kind, amount, etc.; corresponding*

But most surely it is a **pronoun** here:

- the same kind or category of thing
- the very person, thing, or set just mentioned
- **the same**, in the same manner; in an identical or similar way

So it means, "*He lent me some money on the condition that I should return **an equal amount of money** before November*." (not different from that which he lent him)

[**Cambridge Dictionary Definition**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/same)